# Bottle - get query item with unicode characters works in browser, fails with webtest

Tags: python, python-3.x, bottle, webtest

I have the following code in a bottle route:

```
site = request.query.site
```

This works fine from the browser. So if I go to the url:

```
http://myapp.domain/?site=füä
```

site will equal, `füa`.

Trying to simulate this request with WebTest this will result in encoding error inside bottle, which then results in site being empty:

```
res = testapp.get("/?site=füä")
```

Now inside the view site will be an empty string:

```
site = request.query.site
```

Does anyone know what is going on here?

Comment: Is this python 2 or 3?

Comment: It's Python3, but I solved the issue already. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This caused me a lot of head ache, so I am posting this for the benefit of others.
The key to the solution, was the fact that I coppied the URL as is from the browser to my test code.

```
res = testapp.get("/?site=füä")
```

The browser (in my case firefox 50, but also current chrome) silently translate those characters, and all is fine.
After reading more about how bottle handles the FormsDict, I could really confirm that problem is with WebTest. A bit more searching and I found out, that there a long standing bug regarding that:

[quoted urls UnicodeDecodeError](https://github.com/Pylons/webtest/issues/83)

To get around the issue, I simply change the URL in the test code to encoded URL:

```
res = testapp.get("/?site=f%C3%BC%C3%A4")
```

And viola! The problem was solved. Now site is properly set to `füä`. I used 
[HTML URL Encoding Reference](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp).

Lesson learned. Never user unicode naively in test code.